# Problema al mostrar dato en input dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Saludos, tengo un problema al mostrar el total de una operacion que hago entre dos input, el resultado de esa operacion debo mostrarla en otro input automaticamente, sin pulsar un boton ni nada, estos son mis inputs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#monto").change(function() {

    var acumulado = parseInt(0);

    function calcula() {
      var cantidad = parseInt($("#num").val());
      var monto = parseInt($("#monto").val());
      var vecesPorcentaje = Math.floor(cantidad / 3);
      var sobrantes = cantidad - (vecesPorcentaje * 3);

      for (var i = 0; i < vecesPorcentaje; i++) {
        acumulado = acumulado + (monto * 3);
        monto = monto + (monto * 0.2);
      }
      acumulado = acumulado + (monto * sobrantes);
      $("#total").val(acumulado);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="num" placeholder="cantidad"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="monto" placeholder="monto"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="total" disabled value="">
</form>
```

Busco que me aparezca el total de la operacion automaticamente mientras vaya escribiendo en el input con id="monto" pero no me esta mostrando nada y no da errores en console.

Comment: Prueba en lugar del evento **change** usa el **keypress**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo `keyup` que se ejecuta siempre que el usuario escriba y no estas ejecutando la funcion `calcula` para realizar el calculo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#monto").keyup(function(){

  var acumulado = parseInt(0);

   function calcula(){
     var cantidad = parseInt($("#num").val());
     var monto = parseInt($("#monto").val());
     var vecesPorcentaje = Math.floor(cantidad/3);
     var sobrantes = cantidad - (vecesPorcentaje*3);

       for(var i = 0; i< vecesPorcentaje; i++)
       {
            acumulado = acumulado + (monto*3);
            monto = monto + (monto*0.2);
       }
          acumulado = acumulado+(monto*sobrantes);
          $("#total").val(acumulado);
      }
      
      calcula();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="num" placeholder="cantidad" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="monto" placeholder="monto"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="total" disabled value="">
</form>
```

Te recomendaria que elimines la defincion de la funcion ya que por cada letra estarias creando una nueva función y en tu caso, tener una función o no para hacer el calculo, no hace ninguna diferencia.

Aqui el codigo sin la funcion:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#monto").keyup(function(){

      var acumulado = parseInt(0);

         var cantidad = parseInt($("#num").val());
         var monto = parseInt($("#monto").val());
         var vecesPorcentaje = Math.floor(cantidad/3);
         var sobrantes = cantidad - (vecesPorcentaje*3);

           for(var i = 0; i< vecesPorcentaje; i++)
           {
                acumulado = acumulado + (monto*3);
                monto = monto + (monto*0.2);
           }
           acumulado = acumulado+(monto*sobrantes);
           $("#total").val(acumulado);
          
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="num" placeholder="cantidad" ><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="monto" placeholder="monto"><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="total" disabled value="">
    </form>
```

Comment: Gracias Einer solucionado. Thanks Very Much!